# Comma in public variable

Tags: php

I remember reading this code somewhere:

```
<?php

class test {
    public $foo = 6, $bar;
}

$a = new test();
echo $a->foo; //6
echo $a->bar; //no output
```

What does the comma do in `public $foo = 6, $bar;`? Why does my IDE give me error when I remove `public`? I do find out that `$bar` is declared by doing so, but I don't think that's the sole reason why you code it this way though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comma is functionally the same as:

```
<?php
class test {
    public $foo = 6;
    public $bar;
}

$a = new test();
echo $a->foo; //6
echo $a->bar; //no output
```

Basically, it just means declare another public variable.  If you remove public, you're no longer declaring a public variable, so your IDE complains.  The reason people code that way is to save space.  It's just shorthand for a longer form.

Answer (score 3):

> *What does the comma do in public $foo = 6, $bar;?*

It lets you declare two class properties - `$foo` (with default value 6) and `$bar` (with default value `null`) - with the **same access modifier** - `public` - without repeating it twice, like here:

```
public $foo = 6;
public $bar;
```

By the way, `no output` is result of converting this `null` value to string (an empty string).

> *Why does my IDE give me error when I remove public?*

Because you cannot specify a property without specifying its access modifier. Quoting the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> Class member variables are called "properties". [...] They are defined
>   by using one of the keywords `public`, `protected`, or `private`,
>   followed by a normal variable declaration. [...]
>
> In order to maintain backward compatibility with PHP 4, PHP 5 will
>   still accept the use of the keyword `var` in property declarations
>   instead of (or in addition to) `public`, `protected`, or `private`. If you
>   declare a property using `var` instead, then PHP 5 will treat the property as if it had been declared as `public`.

In other words, unless you use `var`, there's no such thing in PHP as `default access modifier` (or special treatment for `no access modifier`) for the member *variables*. And yes, it's kind of an inconsistency - as member *functions* can be defined without access modifier (in that case they are processed as `public`).

... and that's, btw, the reason for that confusing `unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION` error message; that `$foo = 6` statement , in the end, is treated as a function declaration.